# Passing the traceid/context across page reloads?

Tags: open-telemetry

Just a quick question/thought and I have a basic understanding of Open Telemetry.

Aare there a standard/recommendation for passing the traceId/context across page redirects in the browser? (like does the browser support passing the context across a 30x redirect?).

What I wanted to do was to visualize the authentication flow when using OpenID-Connect and I thought it would be very cool if I could pass the traceId across redirects to get a complete picture of all the page loads.

Assuming that I could get the auth service to support it).